# Extend or override Session in ASP.NET (cookieless)

Tags: asp.net, session-state, session-cookies

I have an webapp multi domain and country. And I like to have other HttpCookieMode more complex. I like to mix UseDeviceProfile with country and wap gateway for determinating cookieless. Do you know what class do i have to inherit o method override?

I have tried changing SessionIdManager, but it isn´t work.

Thx in advance,